# A href With echo open in a new window

Tags: php, echo

I want to open this link on a new window: is the following correct?

```html
<a href="<?php echo "$link"; ?><?php echo $userRow['user_wallet']; ?> " target="_blank">Check Your Adress</a>
```

Comment: You could not do it directly with html and php. You need to use javascript or jquery

Answer (score -1):

I Just Find The Way To Open The Link In A New Page The Code Is

```html
<a target = '_blank' href="<?php echo "$link"; ?><?php echo $userRow['user_wallet']; ?>" >Check Your Adress</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `window.open()` of javascript to achieve this.

```
<a onclick="window.open(document.URL, '_blank', 'location=yes,height=700,width=550,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');">Open In New Window</a>
```

This should help you.